# How do I print the age based on the selected date picker on a text field?

Tags: ios, swift

When I select the date the app stops responding. I want to select the date and show it in a textfield without pressing a done button. So I want to see date in live.

How do I print the age based on the selected Date picker on a TextField?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpEmailSegue0: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateBirthday: UITextField!

    @IBAction func dateBirthdayEdit(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy"
        dateBirthday.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }
}
```

Comment: what the issue u faced ..

Comment: add console report

Comment: @Anbu.karthik How do I print the age based on the selected Date picker on a TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows - using `#selector()` and exposing your function to `@objc`

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


@objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateBirthday.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

**To answer your second question of how to get the age:**

```
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let ageComponents = gregorian.dateComponents([.year], from: sender.date, to: Date())
if let age = ageComponents.year {
    print(age)
}
```

Comment: How do I print the age based on the selected date on a TextField?

Comment: Please refer http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-calculate-age-in-swift/ to calculate age from the date

Comment: @rbaldwin How to check email already exists in Firebase swift?

Comment: That is a new topic for a new question.  Start a new question, showing what code you are already trying.